# copy command using JS

Tags: execcommand

Please help me solve this code. I've been fixing this for a month. Thank you for helping!

```js
function copyText(text) {
 text.select();
 try {
  document.execCommand('copy');
 } catch (err) {
  console.log('Unable to copy' + err);
 }
}

copyText('JS is love');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The `.select()` function call doesn't belong to strings but instead `HTMLInputElement` such as TextArea
2. `document.execCommand('copy')` can only run as a result of an user action. In other words, it must belong inside an EventListener such as `'click'`

Please refer to [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript/30810322#30810322) for more details