# How to copy a variable into the clipboard

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I copy a variable into the clipboard?

It always return:

> Uncaught TypeError: copyText.select is not a function

#### Code

```
function copy() {
    var allDesCode2 = document.getElementsByClassName("desCode2");
    var copyText = "ABC";
    for(var i=0; i<allDesCode2.length; i++) {
        copyText += allDesCode2[i].innerHTML;
    }
    copyText.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
}
```

Comment: `.select()` is a `HTMLInputElement` method but you are using it on `String`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript?rq=1) to copy to clipboard.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `copy()` function below can help to copy a string from a variable. You can use this method in pure JavaScript **without the help of any libraries**, such as [jQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery).

```js
function copy() {

    var copyText = "Hooray ! I will be copied";
    var el = document.createElement('textarea');
    el.value = copyText;
    el.setAttribute('readonly', '');
    el.style = {
        position: 'absolute',
        left: '-9999px'
    };
    document.body.appendChild(el);
    el.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(el);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="copy()">Copy</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you were using [this article](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp) as a reference. But in this example `.select()` was used on `<input>` element, and you're trying to execute this method on a variable.

You can look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript) (your question is a possible duplicate of this). It has a plenty of useful answers which will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You just try to select text without any input. That's mistake one. Also I just read the copy event must be inside the click event (maybe there are more events to copy - *[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45517613/copy-command-using-js)*).

I attached the copy function on your div, put its HTML content into the input, and then copy it.

```js
function copy() {
  var allDesCode2 = document.getElementsByClassName("desCode2");
  var copyText = "ABC";
  for (var i = 0; i < allDesCode2.length; i++) {
    copyText += allDesCode2[i].innerHTML;
  }
  $('input').val(copyText).select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
}
$('.desCode2').on('click', copy);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="desCode2">123123123123</div>
<input>
```

Comment: You should take the idea. This code structure is not so good just take the idea you know the drill